# Tensorflow tf.nn.conv2d giving different results for variable vs constant

Tags: python, tensorflow

While converting a model from tensorflow to Pytorch, I ran into a strange issue, where tf.nn.conv2d gives a different result when convolving with the same filters, depending whether a **variable** or a **constant** is used.

I was hoping this to be a bug on my code, but I reduced the problem to a small snippet that gives widely different results on tf.nn.conv2d, that I cannot explain:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.RandomState(42)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
some_input = rng.normal(size=(10, 10, 10, 32)).astype(np.float32)
w_value = rng.normal(size=(5, 5, 32, 64)).astype(np.float32)

variable = tf.Variable(w_value)
sess.run(variable.initializer)

constant = tf.constant(w_value)

with_var = sess.run(tf.nn.conv2d(some_input,
                                 variable,
                                 strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                                 padding='SAME'))


with_const = sess.run(tf.nn.conv2d(some_input,
                                   constant,
                                   strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                                   padding='SAME'))

print('Norm between results: {}'.format(np.linalg.norm(with_var - with_const)))
print('Max diff: {}'.format(np.max(np.abs(with_var - with_const))))

print('Norm between variable and constant: {}'.format(
    np.linalg.norm(sess.run(variable) - sess.run(constant))))
```

On tensorflow 1.11, it gives me a norm of 1.18 between the outputs, which is way too high (it should be 0). I tested both on GPU (GTX 1080) and CPU, and saw differences in both cases.

Any clues to this problem? Using constants should be a very normal operation (e.g. when freezing a graph we convert variables to constants, which should not change the result).

Comment: I won't be able to help you troubleshoot your problem but as a data point for you I received 0.002 between the results when running your code on Tensorflow 1.11.

Comment: Ran the same code on different machines as well, got different norm around 0.003.

Also tried with different data types (float16 and float64), where is respectively increase/lessen the difference. This could point to a rounding error issue.

Comment: Thank you both for reporting the results on other systems. I think that this is still pretty big of a norm (something like 1e-8 may have been acceptable). It is common nowadays to have resnets with 50 - 100 layers, so this error can compound quickly.